# Ajax + Jquery + PHP form sending all anterior emails when submit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, email

I don't know if is a cache problem, but when I send a email after other without refresh the page, form sends all the emails again and the last one. I have already set cache to false, but it doesn't worked. The code is below:

```
function send(datastr,button){
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "sendmail.php",
        data: datastr,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            $(".w-input").val("");
        }
    });
}
```

I don`t know if is a server problem or something like that, please give me help!

Comment: we could do to see more code - like what 'datastr' contains when it is passed in

Comment: How do you call send() method? Looks like you are not reseting datastr and just concatening it with old values

Comment: It`s a form. Datastr contains values as name, date and email, but it is not concatening the value of the variables. If I submit it once, it sends me one email. But when I submit it again, with other values, without refresh the page, it sends me the last one AND the first that I have sent.

Comment: If it was concatening, I'd receive one email with all values sent, but it doesn't. It sends me all emails that was sent before AND the one that i supposed to receive. If I submit form 3 times, at the third time I will receive 3 emails, each one with the respective values that already was sent before.

Comment: How do you attach send function event to button? Try to alert how many times it is being triggered.

Comment: Its a click event, and I call the send function inside a validate function, after I validate the form values. I tested it sending 2 forms, and at the second time it alerts twice. I put alert inside send function, that means it is calling it twice.

Comment: I fixed it after reset the value of datastr after I send it and changing the click event to
    one.("click",function(){})

Comment: the method one didn`t fixed the problem, so I removed it. And thanks, it was really sending twice like the variable was not being reseted but I reseted it inside send function too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reset the value of the variable datastr inside the send function. I use the variable with the same name when I get the values of form inputs and validate it, so datastr contains a string with form data. But I reseted it after pass by send. So when I send again, send already have a value and concatenate it again. I resolve it reseting the variable after complete the ajax request. Thanks.